# Помогите написать логику PHP

Tags: php, html

Введение:
Публикую на сайте статьи и на главной они отображаются (картинка находится с левой стороны а краткий текст с Правой!) и все друг за другом картинка слева а текст с права хотел что бы было так:

Одна статья картинка с лева а текст с права а следующая наоборот
картинка с правой стороны а текст слева!

Comment: Какой код есть на данный момент?

Comment: Решил проблему так    `<?php $fSchet = 0; ?>` `<?php $fShet++; echo ($fShet % 2) ? "myFloatLeft" : "myFloatRight";?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$i - индекс статьи. $align - положение

```
$align = ($i % 2) ? "left" : "right";
```

Ну как-то так, исходя из предоставленной информации.

Comment: Спасибо огромное нашел такое же решение на одном форуме.

Answer (score 0):

Типа этого?

```css
img{max-width:100%;}
#articles section{width:100%}
#articles section:nth-child(2n+1)>div{float:right;}
#articles section:nth-child(2n)>div{float:left;}
#articles section div.img{width:30%}
#articles section div.text{width:70%}
```

```html
<div id="articles">
  <section>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://psd.by/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/twitterman256.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Title1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae dolorum pariatur ipsa ut dicta maxime quisquam incidunt eligendi doloremque earum molestiae dignissimos magni deleniti quaerat accusantium numquam a facilis quibusdam.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/142/4/c/twitter_icon_by_ariimage-d3gxs23.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Title2</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit error voluptatibus harum dignissimos facilis pariatur sit ipsa porro non quam voluptatum soluta suscipit veritatis laudantium doloremque perferendis veniam corporis vel.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://netbu.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/zloi.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Title3</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum non eveniet molestiae ipsum suscipit molestias saepe sit accusantium enim labore quasi dolor quam qui consequuntur quae voluptatum possimus veritatis quidem.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну получилось, что php тут можно и не вмешивать. Выводить стандартным шаблоном, а css все доделает

Comment: В IE8 не взлетит, если это важно.

Comment: Согласен...тогда меняем section на div и добавляем класс left или right вышеопубликованным методом. Ну и в css соответственно вместо nth-child - .left или .right